# Notation for strips in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $L \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace. Let $d >0$. Then let us consider the following "strip" of "core" $L$ and "width" $d$
$$
S := \{x \in \mathbb R^n : \text{dist}(x, L)< \frac{d}{2}\}.
$$

Are the names "strip", "core" and "width" standard in this contest? Is there any standardized notation for these kind of sets?

Comment: I've never seen those words in this context. Nor do I think there's are standard names. Define these as you have. Then you can use them in your document.

Comment: "width" is standard in the sense that everybody will always know what is meant. I haven't heard the name "core" in this context before, though...

Comment: @FlorianR Yeah, I think "width" is pretty safe, I'm more concerned about "core". I don't know if it is appropriate enough. I was also considering the word "soul", but it might sound too pretentious :D

Comment: I think core is fine. We definitely talk about the core of the Mobius band which is a strip of sorts, (but of an $(n-2)$-manifold), so the terminology isn't something that isn't used in something related. But I've never seen it used like this before. You might call it a $\frac{d}{2}$-neighbourhood of $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use B(L,d/2), the "ball" about L within d/2 of L.